# Oracle SQL CTE (Common Table Expression) where no data

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I'm building a very complex SQL query in Oracle using multiple CTEs, where latter expressions rely on values from former ones. However I find that the whole execution halts if one of the prior CTEs contains no data. For example:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
    (
    SELECT
        PEOPLE.ID AS PID,
        APPLICATIONS.DATE AS APPDATE
    FROM
        PEOPLE,
        APPLICATIONS
    WHERE
        APPLICATIONS.PERSON_ID = PEOPLE.ID
        AND APPLICATIONS.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
    ),
CTE2 AS
    (
    SELECT
        APPLICATIONS.PERSON_ID AS PID
        MIN(APPLICATIONS.DATE) AS EARLIEST_APPDATE
    FROM
        CTE1,
        APPLICATIONS
    WHERE
        APPLICATIONS.PERSON_ID = CTE1.PID
        AND APPLICATIONS.DATE < ADD_MONTHS(CTE1.APPDATE, -18)
    GROUP BY APPLICATIONS.PERSON_ID
    ),
MAIN_QUERY AS
    (
    SELECT
        CTE1.PID AS PID
    FROM
        CTE1, CTE2
    WHERE
        -- Note that the PIDs should either match, or should not exist in CTE2
        CTE1.PID = CTE2.PID OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT PID FROM CTE2 WHERE CTE1.PID = CTE2.PID))
    )
SELECT
    MAIN_QUERY.PID
FROM MAIN_QUERY
```

Of course, I realise that the above example is completely pointless in itself, however I have just simplified this to illustrate the problem. CTE2 returns the earliest date of any application made by the same Person ID where the application is dated more than 18 months prior to the application date of CTE1. However... what if there are no such applications? CTE2 is capable of returning zero rows.

You will notice that CTE2 is not, in itself, referenced in the final query. An empty CTE2 is dealt with in MAIN_QUERY. So with regards the final query, it should not matter whether CTE2 actually returns any lines or not.

However the application I'm using (Business Objects) throws up an error that the query has "no data to fetch", when CTE2 has no lines.

I want to find a way around this, to enable my query to execute even if CTE2 returns null. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should start using an explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the old outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are after, but I think a simple outer join `main_query` would do: `from cte1 left join cte2 on cte1.pid = cte2.pid`

Comment: Thanks - but as I said, the real query is very much more complex than the example, and I'm not sure how joins would work: I have at least *three* preparatory CTEs which need to be executed before the main query, and within each CTE there's a load of complex stuff going on. I have no idea how I would proceed with joins. I understand CTEs, so that's what I'm working with. Grateful if anyone can assist - thanks.

Comment: If you're not sure how an outer join would help you here, I highly recommend that you research joins.

Comment: @Boneist: an outer join **is** a join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I know. I'm not entirely sure the OP does, though!

Comment: Yes - I need a lot more practice with joins!

Answer (score 1):

> CTE2 returns the earliest date of any application made by the same Person ID where the application is dated more than 18 months prior to the application date of CTE1. However... what if there are no such applications? CTE2 is capable of returning zero rows.

You can replace your [sub-query factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2161315) (`WITH ... AS ( ... )`) clauses with a simple analytical function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE ( id ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE APPLICATIONS ( id, person_id, "DATE" ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2015-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- First row to return
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2014-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Within 18 months
SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2013-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Before 18 months
SELECT 4, 1, DATE '2012-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Before 18 months and min
SELECT 5, 2, DATE '2015-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Second row to return
SELECT 6, 2, DATE '2014-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Within 18 months
SELECT 7, 3, DATE '2015-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Third row to return
SELECT 8, 3, DATE '2013-07-03' FROM DUAL;          -- Exactly 18 months earlier
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT PID,
       APPDATE,
       CASE EARLIEST_APPDATE
            WHEN APPDATE - INTERVAL '18' MONTH
            THEN NULL
            ELSE EARLIEST_APPDATE
            END AS EARLIEST_APPDATE -- Included for the edge case where
                                    -- EARLIEST_APPDATE is exactly 18 months
                                    -- earlier as the RANGE BETWEEN is
                                    -- inclusive.
FROM   (
  SELECT p.ID AS PID,
         a."DATE" AS APPDATE,
         MIN( a."DATE" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY p.ID
                                ORDER BY     a."DATE"
                                RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                          AND INTERVAL '18' MONTH PRECEDING )
           AS EARLIEST_APPDATE
  FROM   PEOPLE p
         INNER JOIN APPLICATIONS a
         ON ( a.PERSON_ID = p.ID )
)
WHERE  APPDATE BETWEEN DATE '2015-01-01' AND DATE '2015-01-31'
```

**Output**:

```
       PID APPDATE             EARLIEST_APPDATE  
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 2015-01-01 00:00:00 2012-01-01 00:00:00 
         2 2015-01-02 00:00:00                     
         3 2015-01-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your efforts - however this didn't assist, because as I said in my question the actual query is highly complex, and the example I gave was just a representation of what I am doing. Not only do I not have a clue about all the "unbounded preceding" stuff, but I'm also not sure if it's even possible to use joins to replace what I'm doing with multiple CTEs. Anyway... since posting, I have found a way round it: using nested queries instead of all the CTEs! But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation as you will miss out on a lot of features that will greatly simplify everything if you just dismiss things you don't know about. The `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is the windowing clause of an [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) that will restrict the value you are finding the minimum to to have the same `ID` and be more than 18 months earlier.